# Can linode make django deployment simple?

Tags: django, deployment, scalability, heroku, linode

I am designing a website and am debating if I should go with 
                     rails or django, my preference leans towards django but the fact 
                     that heroku makes deployment and sys admin tasks very easy I 
                     might go with rails+heorku. Can linode provide a nice platform 
                     that is easy to maintain and scale for uploading django 
                     projects? I am able to use linux effeciently but would like to 
                     focus more on the software aspects as opposed to hardware/server 
                     stuff.

I've heard some bad things about app engine and have decided not to bother with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using linode for almost 4 years now and I have tried a variety of solutions like Amazon EC2, Heroku and MediaTemple.

You are on your own if you go for Amazon EC2 and the performance isn't as good as Linode's.  Heroku is great if you don't want to customize your kernel or worry too much about distro level library installs, but that also means that there's some limitation on what you can do on Heroku - you don't have access to the filesystem for example.

I don't really like Mediatemple that much but that's just my experience with them.

Linode's technical support is unbeatable.

For "one-click installs", and if you don't mind shared hosting, webfaction is the solution.

If you want to automate your server set-up on linode.com, you can consider stackscripts as mentioned by @eakron above.  Or you can write your own fabric scripts. See http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Like Shintoist said, Linode does offer stack scripts that make for easier Django setup and deployment. We developed a Django website on Linode, but decided to set everything up manually. It took approximately an hour to set up the system and the necessary modules. We haven't restarted or touched the system since.

Comment: How reliable do you find linode? Can it scale well, load pages quickly, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Linode is a great VPS provider but is not really the same thing as Heroku. You could search their [StackScripts](http://www.linode.com/stackscripts/) for a "one button" solution, but really you're going to need to set things up yourself. It doesn't need to be difficult but it will add some overhead to your web development

If you're still just starting out I suggest you with Ruby on Rails, but if you've got your heart set on Python/Django (I do prefer it myself), it doesn't have to be hard. The Linode Library has lots of basic setup guides for a simple Django setup [here.](http://library.linode.com/search?query=django)

Finally I'd suggest you sign up for the private beta of [djangy.com](https://www.djangy.com/) which is the same thing as Heroku, for Django. Still far from finished tho.